# Unable to locate the Javac Compiler maven sonar:sonar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sdk, sonarqube

I am trying to analyze a project with sonar.

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

The Problem I get:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\sepm_git\qse-sepm-ws12-02\vpm>mvn clean install -DskipTe
sts=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building vpm 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ vpm ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\user\Desktop\sepm_git\qse-sepm-ws12-02\vpm\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ vpm ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\user\Desktop\sepm_git\qse-
sepm-ws12-02\vpm\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ vpm ---
[INFO] Compiling 92 source files to C:\Users\user\Desktop\sepm_git\qse-sepm-ws
12-02\vpm\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.920s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 21 15:43:57 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
3.2:compile (default-compile) on project vpm: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\..\lib\tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
C:\Users\user\Desktop\sepm_git\qse-sepm-ws12-02\vpm>
```

However,

my java home var is set to:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME% 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
```

in eclipse under preferences I set:

[image]

Any idea why it does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're pointing to a Java Runtime Environment (JRE), not a Java Development Kit

```
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
```

The JRE simply contains the JVM (`java.exe`) and associated libs etc. The JDK is a superset of this and contains the JRE + compiler (`javac.exe)` and associated tools. You're normally install the JRE on production boxes that don't require the compiler, and the JDK in development environments.

Answer (score 0):

Set your JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_09

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and i solved it by setting JRE to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre in eclipse luna.

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1**: The following steps would work for Eclipse:

1. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs
2. Edit the existing JRE location as: Set JRE Home = JAVA_HOME or JAVA_HOME\jre (In your case the path should be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09 OR C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre)
3. Click Finish and OK button

**Way 2**: Another way to set the JRE System Library:

1. Open eclipse and Right click on Eclipse project Properties
2. Java Build Path -> Libraries
3. Select JRE System Library -> Click Edit button
4. Click "Installed JREs..." button
5. Edit JRE as: Set JRE Home = JAVA_HOME or JAVA_HOME\jre

**Way 3**: The following steps should also work well:

1. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs
2. Select the JRE you are using
3. Press Edit -> Add External JARs...
4. Browse to Java\jdk1.7.0_09\lib and select tools.jar and Press Enter
5. Click Finish and OK button